# what class should be imported to use Execution exception in java

Tags: android

which class should be imported to use execution exception in android?

This is the code where i was using AsynckTask class and Eceptions.please provide me the solution as i am a begginer to this

```
package com.nehagupta.downloadingwebcontent;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i("URL",params[0]);
        return "Done";

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DownloadTask task=new DownloadTask();
    String result = null;
    try{
        result=task.execute("https://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk/").get();

    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(ExecutionException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("Result",result);
}
```

}

Error:(35, 15) error: cannot find symbol class ExecutionException

Comment: thank you it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Studio, then the IDE should be able to import this class for you by highlighting over it and viewing the error. If this is not the case, then I would suggest just changing the `ExecutionException` to a general `Exception` and continuing to carry on coding.

The import for the new exception will be `java.lang.Exception`.